# How to Swap or Clone RAID 0 to Single HDD of 1 TB

Tags: ubuntu, raid-0

The problem scenario that I am trying to accomplish. Currently I have a Ubuntu Server Setup with H/W RAID 0 with 2 * 2TB disks as 4T. However, we realized later that the server does not require that large HDD size, hence we have a new server for which we can use this 2 * 2T disks for setup.

Since the data and critical setup has been already done on the existing RAID 0 server. Is there any way to :

Clone the RAID 0 to new 1TB HDD that can be attached to the server. (Get exact replica of the RAID 0 which has only 42 GB data to the new 1TB hard disk). Or could anyone suggest how I can migrate the HDD from RAID to No RAID without losing data. Appreciate your help.

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/isw_beiffigejf_SAT2 3.6T 42G 3.4T 2% /
udev 16G 4.0K 16G 1% /dev
tmpfs 6.3G 384K 6.3G 1% /run
none 5.0M 0 5.0M 0% /run/lock
none 16G 0 16G 0% /run/shm
/dev/mapper/isw_beiffigejf_SAT1 95M 120K 95M 1% /boot/efi
```

dmraid -s - Output

```
*** Group superset isw_beiffigejf
--> Active Subset
name : isw_beiffigejf_SAT
size : 7813988864
stride : 256
type : stripe
status : ok
subsets: 0
devs : 2
spares : 0
```

Comment: what FS are you using? Quick answer: Add new 1TB disk,Boot something like grml, Shrink the FS (and the LV), lvmove, chroot into system on 1TB disk, reinstall grub (and, if needed, cleanup fstab and md), remove 2x2TB disks, done.